# How to use DynamicJasper to create an excel spreadsheet with formulas for subtotals of columns?

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I would like to like to produce a Excel spreadsheet using DynamicJasper that computes subtotals of columns using formulas.  For example:

```
Employee   Department        Expenses
----------------------------------------
Alice      Sales             $600.00
Bob        IT                $400.00
Charlie    IT                $450.00

           Sales subtotal    $600.00 
           IT subtotal       $850.00
```

I want the bottom two rows to be produced in such a way that the numbers are the result of Excel formulas, so that if the hours were edited, the subtotals would change.

I'm encountering various difficulties currently.  If I set the `Expenses` column to have type `double`, then DynamicJasper inserts `$` and makes it a string.  (Thus addition becomes impossible.)  But a more basic problem is how to define a cell to be a subtotal of cells above it.

I would be pleased if anyone could point me towards an example that simply totaled a column, so long as it used excel formulas to accomplish it.

Answer (score 2):

it would do something like this, and this is not tested or anything:

```
GroupBuilder gb1 = new GroupBuilder("column_name");

gb1.addFooterVariable(frb.getColumn("column_name_with_amounts"),CALCULATION.EMPTY,style_lala,getBigDecimalFormatter());
```

getBigDecimalFormatter is:

```
private DJValueFormatter getBigDecimalFormatter(f) {
    return new DJValueFormatter(){

        public Object evaluate(Object value, Map fields, Map variables, Map parameters) {

            return "here is excel code for calculating like sum=SUM(A1:A15)";
        }

        public String getClassName() {
            return String.class.getName();
        }};
}
```

thats about it, but beware: you have to have full control over the data you are creating report from. At `getBigDecimalFormatter` for instance you have to know which rows in column you are calculating. Generally i have 2d Object array for data and i can  from Map fields determine everything i need.

In my opinion is quite a lot of work, but i am not that familiar with dynamicJasper, using it for a little while now...Maybe for xls format you don't even need `getBigDecimalFormatter`, just `b1.addFooterVariable()`.

But on other hand if you just create plain table of data and then user in Excel with one button creates sums, which is not that much work anyway:)

Take care,Nb